# Passing unescaped querystring in BackboneJS

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, query-string

I am trying to pass a querystring based on different selections from 4 drop down lists. I am passing the querystring by a variable but it is being escaped and thus the result is 404 Error.

Here is the code that I am writing for making the querystring...

```
      function setQueryString(product,brand,demographic,region)
     {
      product =  dropdownlists.get('Product');
      brand = dropdownlists.get('Brand');
      demographic = dropdownlists.get('Demographic');
      region = dropdownlists.get('Region');
      if(product !=='' && brand !=='' && demographic !=='' && region !=='')
        {
           queryString = 'product='+product+'&'+'brand='+brand+'&'+'demographic='+demographic+'&'+'region='+region ;
           return queryString;
        }
      else{console.log('nevermind!!');}
     }
```

`There is a view function updating the DataModel model with selected values every time user makes a selection.Based on these selections we get (colorscale) data from the server.`

```
    var DataModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
              urlRoot : '/api/web/',
              idAttribute: 'value',
              defaults : {
                 Product : '',
                 Brand : '',
                 Demographic : '',
                 Region : ''
             }
      });
    var dropdownlists = new DataModel();



    var colorscalelist = new ColorScaleModel({value: setQueryString()});
         colorscalelist.fetch({success: function(){
         console.log(colorscalelist);
        }
      });
```

And the Colorscale Model is:

```
    var ColorScaleModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot : '/api/web/colorscale',
    idAttribute: 'value',
    defaults : {
            DPRBID: " ",
            F: "",
            BR1: " ",
            BR2: " ",
            BR3: " ",
            UN: " ",
            C: " ",
            T: " "
      }
        });
```

The URL that is being passed is converted to ASCII characters. Is there any way to pass it directly, unescaped. Or, is there any other way to approach this problem of sending the data. Its my first project of BackboneJS and any help would be great. 
Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of a string your function `setQueryString()` should return a query object.
So instead of

```
queryString = 'product='+product+'&'+'brand='+brand+'&'+'demographic='+demographic+'&'+'region='+region
```

you should return

```
{
    product: product,
    brand: brand,
    demographic: demographic,
    region: region
}
```

Then, in the `fetch` call pass this object as the `data` parameter. Something like

```
colorscalelist.fetch({ data: getQuery(), success: function() { ... } });
```

(`getQuery()` returns the above object, seems to me to be a better name than `setQueryString()` ...)

The `fetch` function will then serialize your query object into a query string and perform all necessary escaping.

Answer (score 1):

Ajax operations in Backbone are ultimately delegated to jQuery and as such accept options that will modify the request. To add request parameters, you can pass a `data` parameter that will be transmitted as a query string.

For example,

```
var ColorScaleModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url : '/api/web/colorscale',

    defaults : {
    }
});

var dropdownlists = new DataModel({
    Product : 'P1',
    Brand : 'B1',
    Demographic : 'D1',
    Region : 'R1'
});

var colorscalelist = new ColorScaleModel();
colorscalelist.fetch({
   data: dropdownlists.toJSON() 
});
```

will result in a request to `/api/web/colorscale?Brand=B1&Demographic=D1&Product=P1&Region=R1`

See http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/wufbL/ for a demo

You could take this a step further and incorporate the filters in your model by overriding `model.fetch`. For example:

```
var ColorScaleModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url : '/api/web/colorscale',

    defaults : {
    },

    initialize: function(attrs, opts) {
        this.filters = opts.filters;
    },

    fetch: function(opts) {
        opts = opts || {};
        opts.data = this.filters.toJSON();

        return Backbone.Model.prototype.fetch.call(this, opts);
    }
});

var dropdownlists  = new DataModel();
var m = new ColorScaleModel({}, {filters: dropdownlists});
m.fetch();

f.set({Product: "P1", Brand: "B1"});
m.fetch();
```

And a Fiddle to play with http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/wufbL/1/